# how to extract author details from pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf

I have 1000s and 1000s of PDF articles from which I need to extract only author name and his relevant details like `address` and `email ID` and whatever provided inside the PDF (I mean the content inside). I don't want to do this by getting the details associated with the metadata of the PDF. Since I tried that where I end up with only less details like author name, title and some other usual details which I do not need at all.

I have gone via all APIs in internet, but still I did get the solution. I need to do it in Java.

Comment: So this stuff is just text within the pdf? Are they in the same place in your 1000s of files?

Comment: Satish, are you *assuming* that every PDF document you are working with contains details like 'Author`, etc? AFAIK, data like `Author`, `Title`, `AuthorEmail` are part of `document metadata`.

Comment: 'yes' for the just text and 'no' for the same place. since those are articles from different sources. hey and if have solution for the 'same place' that which you have refereed please you are welcome to provide that.

Comment: I ask because then it becomes a lot more contextual and dependent on the data contained within the actual PDFs. There are no generic solutions if this information is scattered all over the place across these PDFs, you will have to just write a scanner that will contextually find this data, or use heuristics to scan through the document for locations of where they are.

Comment: hey what are those scanner and heuristics

Comment: Satish *[birryree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766690/how-to-extract-author-details-from-pdf-using-java#comment13997168_10766690)* advises you to write parser to find such data in the text read from PDF applying proper biz logic.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk - heuristics are defined by you, I don't know anything about your data set (the PDFs). The scanner is also defined by you, you have better knowledge of these PDFs than any of us do. Likely, you will have to do some manual inspection into the PDFs first, and see what their data looks like when read through a PDF library like iText, then determine how your code logic will handle the various cases/locations in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't get it directly from any library.
Use iTest library for [reading](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html) pdf. Once you are able to read text find the Author using regular expression.

Comment: Ya! and I to have the same Idea but I'm new to Regular expression and also searching some alternative solution. If Regular expression is the only solution kindly guide me how to use Regular expression and extract these details form String that I get from iText result.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk - u may start with this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) . and check the [PRDReader class](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html) .